# No suitable image found for libswiftAVFoundation.dylib. Code signature invalid

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode

I'm getting the following error when I try to include my framework written in Swift to an old project that's written in Objective-C (created with CMAKE)

dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/abcdefg-hijklmn/myapp.app/Frameworks/MyFramework.framework/MyFramework
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/abcdefg-hijklmn/myapp.app/Frameworks/MyFramework.framework/Frameworks/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/abcdefg-hijklmn/myapp.app/Frameworks/MyFramework.framework/MyFramework/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib'

I've signed my framework with codesign in terminal as well as enabled "always embed swift standard libraries." Anyone know what could be the problem?

Comment: What MacOS version are you having the error on, we've got a similar problem... :)

Comment: Getting same problem,  running in Xcode 9.2. But in Xcode 10.2 is working. Any leads for Xcode 9.2 or macos el-captain.